# how can I add a list of images in a class?

Tags: c#, image, list

ATTENTION: The class is in a my external DLL implemented in my project.
Inside my class library there is this class Annuncio 
with a list inside.
The list must contain images, but my code gives me an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BuyNowDLL
{
    class Annuncio
    {
       public List<Image> Images1 = new List<Image>();  //Make me error (Image)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x55qZ.png)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: How could we possibly answer this without knowing what the error is?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in. The errore is: the type or namespace name 'Image' was not found. Probably missing a directive using or assembly reference. @BogdanDoicin

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any errors, it is because you have not referenced the System.Drawing.dll

Right click on the project name in the solution explorer, and click on Add > Reference

then choose check `System.Drawing` in the list of Assemblies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I haven't read that comment

Comment: no problem. happens ;)

Comment: Ok, 
but the class is inside my dll.
How can I add references to it? @AshkanMobayenKhiabani

Comment: You have imported the namespace (`using System.Drawing;`) just follow the step to add the reference to the dll.

Comment: But the node References there isn't. Please can you look the image in my question @AshkanMobayenKhiabani

Comment: @jck91 "dipendenze" is right there on your image. Right click it and select the option to add one.